# MySQL Views and Restricting Insert/Updates

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently using MySQL views and a User Defined Variable (i.e. SET @UserID = 4;) to limit the data that is returned from underlying tables to ensure data is specific to that user.

My inserts/updates are also calling the same views, but the 'WHERE uid = @UserID' obviously only applies to selects. Is there any way to ensure that any update statements for a user follow the same condition? (i.e. they can only update rows they own?)

Thanks!

Comment: your where clause will do that too.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have control over the SQL statements?

Comment: I don't think its possible in MySQL as trigger on view is not supported in MySQL. So you will have to handle this check in your application logic or inside a stored procedure.